# Download from slideshare with python

Tags: python, python-requests

im trying to download the powerpoints from SlideShare, using the code that follows:

```
import requests
 
url = 'https://es.slideshare.net/accenture/accenture-tech-vision-2020-trend-1?from_action=save'
myfile = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(myfile.content)
open('presentation.pdf', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

The fact is that I got to identificate myself and then press a button on that link that downloads the presentation, but the code is not working, why I'm failing?

Comment: This code doesn't click or authenticate, and isn't the direct url for the slidedeck (assuming there is one)

Comment: And how could I click with requests library? When I click the download button doesn't generate a new URL, so I can't use that URL with requests.

Comment: better use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which can control real web browser, click buttons, fill form, etc. `requests` gives you only HTML of this page, but it can't click buttons and fill forms - you would have to create more `reuqests` to simulate click and fill form - and this need much more work. You would have use DevTool in browser to see what browser sends to server and do the same with requests. And if browser will use JavaScript to generate some value then you have to do the same in Python. And you have to also keep cookies. All this is much simpler with Selenium